# Deleting a node from a doubly linked list AND freeing up its space as well

Tags: c++, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I'm working on an assignment and there's a problem I'm stuck on. So I'm making a doubly linked list. I want a a delete function that will take item as argument, search for that argument in the list. when it has found the node which contains that item, I have to DELETE that node. I am aware of how I would change the previous and next pointers to the the nodes around that node. The problem that has been bugging me however, is that when I just change the next pointer of the node before it and the previous pointer of the node after it, like in the code below, the particular node will only be disconnected from the list but it will still remain in the freestore. How do I delete it from there so that the memory it is taking is also freed?

The following is the code I have. Please take a look:

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::deleteElement(T item)
{
    ListItem<T> *curPtr;
    curPtr = searchFor(item); // this function returns the pointer to the node which contains the item.
    (curPtr->next)->prev = curPtr->prev;
    (curPtr->prev)->next = tempPtr->next;


}
```

So you see, the curPtr is being disconnected, but I believe it still exists somewhere on the freestore. How do I get rid of it permanantly?

Comment: how about delete item;  delete curPtr;  ?

Comment: Note that aside from using `delete` to get the object destroyed and the memory returned to the memory manager there are some issues with your code: you need to handle the cases where no node is found or the found node is the first, last, or only node (unless you use a sentinel node for the begin and end of the list). Also, `tempPtr` seems wrong.

Comment: @sithereal "how about delete item; delete curPtr;" - `delete item;` would be wrong. Only `delete curPutr` is needed.

Comment: @davmac only if we know that ListItem<T> class also deletes the instance of T. do we know? no

Comment: @sithereal It's nothing to do with whether ListItem<T> also deletes instances of T. `item` is of type `T`, it is not (necessarily) a pointer. You cannot delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you make an `erase_next()` method for your ListItem type?
I have something like the following in a similar class. Hope it helps.

```
void erase_next() {
    // ensure it is not the last item
    if(this->next != nullptr) {
        // create a temporary pointer
        ListItem<T>* tmp = this->next

        // link next to the next item to the next item and change the
        // next items previous item to this item
        this->next = this->next->next;
        next->prev = this;

        // delete the old next item
        delete tmp;
    }
}
```

In your function you could call it with something like the following. Thanks to @davmac edits have been made to delete the first item

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::deleteElement(T item)
{
    ListItem<T> *curPtr = searchFor(item);
    if(curPtr->prev == nullptr) {
        curPtr->next->prev = nullptr;
        delete curPtr;
    } else {
        curPtr->prev->erase_next()
    }
 }
```

**Edit:**

I played around with this again, and you should be able to optimize the `erase_next()` function with the following

```
void erase_next() {
    if(this->next != nullptr) {
        this->next = this->next->next
        // We've already linked next so we can delete the handle
        // with prev Note: this method is not possible with a
        // single linked list and we would need the temp variable
        delete this->next->prev
        next->prev = this;
    }
}
```

That way you don't have to declare a temp variable.

Comment: No problem! I'm glad it helped. If you want to optimize the function, you may consider changing searchFor(item) to return a pointer to the item before the one you want, so that you can call `searchFor(item)->erase_next()` as your entire function body, or you could just opt for pointer arithmetic and use `(searchFor(item) - 1)->erase_next()`.

Comment: What if the item to delete is the first in the list? (i.e. there is no previous item to call `erase_next` on).

Comment: Killer question! You would have to make an exception and add a `erase_prev()` function

Comment: I added edits taking into consideration the comments by @davmac